# Не происходит заполнение массива, программа завершается после первой итерации. Также выдаёт проблему не обработанного исключения

Tags: c++, visual-c++, исключения, динамические-массивы

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");


    int number_of_channels, frequency_len;

    cout << "Введите число частот:" << endl;
    cin >> frequency_len;

    cout << "Введите число каналов:" << endl;
    cin >> number_of_channels;


    float** connection_probability = new float* [frequency_len];       
    for (int i = 0; i < frequency_len; i++)
        float* connection_probability = new float[number_of_channels + 1];  // + 1 для того чтобы в 0м элементе каждого из массивов хранить величину частоты


    for (int i = 0; i < frequency_len; i++) {
        cout << "Введите значение " << i + 1 << "й частоты:" << endl;
        cin >> connection_probability[i][0];
        for (int j = 1; j < number_of_channels + 1; j++) {
            cout << "Вероятность соединения с " << j << "м каналом --> ";
            cin >> connection_probability[i][j];
        }
        
    }
    

    for (int i = 0; i < frequency_len; i++) {
        cout << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < number_of_channels + 1; j++) {
            cout << connection_probability[i][j] << "   ";

        }

    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема в строке

```
float* connection_probability = new float[number_of_channels + 1];
```

Сейчас внутри цикла на каждой итерации создается новая переменная `connection_probability` в которую сохраняется адрес выделенной памяти, а после итерации эта переменная удаляется. Это становится причиной утечки пямяти и указатели в массиве остаются невалидными. Чтобы исправить ситуацию нужно заменить вышеуказанную строку на

```
connection_probability[i] = new float[number_of_channels + 1];
```